# JAVA basic coding. Why 100/1=110, as 300/3 ,400/4, 500/5 do?

Tags: java, math, operators, calculator

I need an help to figure out what happened.
I am an Italian speaker so some variable I have name it in Italian.
After some time of no-coding, I've started to code something basic and easy. I made a Class named "Prova" which was a calculator.
4 methods: add, minus, product and divide.
First three method had no anomaly, the last one had.
I made a runnable class and saw some strange result

Here's the code:

```
    public class Prova {
    public int add(int addendo1, int addendo2) {
       int res;
       res = addendo1+addendo2;
       return res;
    }
    public int minus(int minuendo, int sottraendo) {
       int res;
       res = minuendo-sottraendo;
       return res;
    }
    public int multiply(int fattore1, int fattore2) {
       int res;
       res = fattore1*fattore2;
       return res;
    }
    public double divide(int divisore, int dividendo) {
       double res;
       res = divisore/dividendo;
       return res;
    }`
```

Here's the command:
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Prova somma = new Prova();
    System.out.println(somma.add(5, 5)+"\n");
    System.out.println(differenza.minus(20, 11)+"\n");
    System.out.println(new Prova().product(2, 4)+"\n\n");
    System.out.println(new Prova().divide(100, 1)+'\n');
    System.out.println(new Prova().divide(100, 2)+'\n');
    System.out.println(new Prova().divide(300, 3)+'\n');
    System.out.println(new Prova().divide(400, 4)+'\n');
    System.out.println(new Prova().divide(500, 5)+'\n');
    System.out.println(new Prova().divide(600, 6)+'\n');
}
```

And here my results:

```
- 10        //somma.add(5,5) 
- 9         //differenza.minus(20,11)
- 8         //multiply(2,4) 
- 110.0     //divide(100,1)
- 60.0      //divide(100,2)
- 110.0     //divide(300,3)
- 110.0     //divide(400,4)
- 110.0     //divide(500,5)
- 110.0     //divide(600,6)
```

Other tries with divide method had given

```
14/2 = 17.0;
1/1 = 11.0;
2/2 = 11.0;
3/3 = 11.0;
```

The operator works fine outside my Class Prova.divide(). My question is what happened here? I can't see what I did wronf

Comment: Integer math. Change `res = divisore/dividendo;` to `res = divisore/(double)dividendo;`

Comment: As both of these `divisore/dividendo`  are integers, then you will do integer division

Comment: You're essentially trying to concatenate a newline character `\n` to a `double`, but it's actually adding `10`, as `(int) '\n'` is `10`.  You can use `"\n"` instead so it will actually concatenate a newline character.  I was about to post it as an answer, but it was marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell that you want to concatenate a newline character (`'\n'`) to your result. Because you're returning your result as a `double`, you cannot simply add `'\n'` to the result, as it will use its corresponding `int` value (`10`). This shows why you receive `110` when you divide `100` by `1` and then add `'\n'`.

To fix this, I would change `'\n'` to `"\n"` so your result will be coerced to a `String` first.

Also, if you decide to divide anything where the result is a fraction, you'll run into unexpected integer division. See: [Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Note: Because you're using `System.out.println`, there isn't really a need to append newline characters anyway!

Comment: Very nicely spotted; but one additional suggestion. Prefer `System.lineSeparator()` to `"\n"` (or use `printf` and `%n`).